# Angular.js - does form validation emit any events?

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

The problem is, I'm using ui-router and I have two views, one is kind of a toolbar, second is content with a form.

Now I'd like to have a save button in the toolbar, which would be disabled if form was not `$valid`. But those two are on completely different scopes, it's like:

- rootScope

  - toolbar scope
  - content scope(with `form.$valid`)

So I thought I'd deal with it by listening on some kind of $valid events emitted by the form.

According to what Vojta said [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/O7A_YwLkbKw/d5cEtms5UN0J) those events should exist, but I can't find them specified anywhere.. and looking at [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/form.js) I don't see any events..

I could probably do

```
$scope.$watch('form.$valid', function(newVal, oldVal) {
   $scope.$emit('validityChange', {'form':newVal});
});
```

but it feels like using events rather than this would be better

Or should I try something completely different? Note that I can't put toolbar's ui-view inside content's ui-view.. and accordin to [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/187), two ui-views simply can't have the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question directly: 
I am not aware of native form events in angularjs. But, as you know, you can create your own events easily and that would solve your problem.

But here is my suggestion:
You are trying to make two controllers to communicate with each other. Using events may be the wrong approach. Events should really be used for application wide notifications such as authentication.

You can refactor the form and submit button into two directives that share the same controller. While they will not share a scope, they will share a controller object that can be used to communicate. I would do it this way.

Another approach is to nest the two scopes into each other. Move the form code into a higher level controller. Like this:

- rootScope

  - main // your form code here

    - toolbar // submit button has access to functionality
    - content // form has access to functionality

Hope that helps!

Comment: Was this answer not appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both your views must be having different states, and both are in the same Main Controller and Main HTML Page, you can use their state names along with ng-if to specify your condition.

Lets say "**content**" state is for your content view.

Now in your HTML div tag that contains your toolbar, mention a condition something in your **save button field**, similar to this i.e.

```
ng-if = $state.current.name === 'content' && 'nameOfYourForm'.$valid
```

If this condition is satisfied, indirectly means your form is valid.

However, you will have to write this in the run method, which should be declared on the same js file as your module declaration viz.

```
angular.module('nameOfModule' , ['dependency1', ..]). run(run)
```

And then in your run method, inject the $rootScope and $state, and declare and define it like this:

```
function run(stateHandler, .. ,$rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
}
```